# AppleScript: how do I store folders' pathnames into an array, replacing spaces with "\ "?

Tags: path, applescript, find-and-replace, characters, whitespace

I have a folder and inside this folder there's a bunch of subfolders. Using AppleScript I wish to store the pathnames of these subfolders into an array.

Here's my problem: each pathname containing " " (spaces), I want to replace with pathnames containing UNIX-friendly "`\` " notation (backslash followed by a space; as in `/my/fancy\ path/`).

As you can see, I'm only half-way through my goal here. I've spent a good night's worth of laborious attempts, fooling around with `replace_chars` subroutines, `do shell script`-with-`sed` combos and who knows what. No dice.

```
tell application "Finder"

    set myRepos to name of folders of folder ("/Users/hced/Dropbox/GitHub/" as POSIX file)
    --> {"320andup", "Baseline.js (jQuery & vanilla JS version)", "Bootstrap (HTML, CSS, and JS toolkit from Twitter)", "Chirp.js (Tweets on your website, simply)", "Coordino"}

end tell
```

**Edit:** a valid path example would be `/Users/hced/Dropbox/GitHub/A\ folder\ named\ with\ spaces`

Comment: Are you trying to escape the paths to pass back into a shell command?

Comment: adayzdone: yes. I want to iterate over the items in the array via a macro in Keyboard Maestro (it's a bit complicated to explain the full story). Also, some part of the question is just because I'm curious.

Comment: Actually – and this is probably not the (or *a*) recommended way of doing things git-wise, but – my end goal is to parse my GitHub folder for subfolders one level down and then mass-`git fetch` in all of the repos. Brutal, yes, but I didn't find a way of doing it within GitHub.app (Mac), and all the projects are just things I'm not touching (forking) myself, I just want the newest of everything. The choice of AppleScript in this case is because I will store the contents of myRepos as variable in Keyboard Maestro... Sounds like a mess? Indeed, but there's the story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading your question, I'm not sure if you are able to use quoted path names instead of escaping the spaces...

```
tell application "Finder"
        set folderGitHub to folder ("/Users/hced/Dropbox/GitHub/" as POSIX file)

        set listFolders to (every folder in folderGitHub as alias list)
end tell

set listPosixPathsQuoted to {}

repeat with aliasFolder in listFolders
        set listPosixPathsQuoted to listPosixPathsQuoted & {quoted form of POSIX path of aliasFolder}
end repeat
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set myRepos to name of folders of folder ("/Users/hced/Dropbox/GitHub/" as POSIX file)
end tell

repeat with theIndex from 1 to number of items in myRepos
    set item theIndex in myRepos to replace_chars(item theIndex in myRepos, " ", "\\ ")
end repeat

return myRepos

on replace_chars(this_text, search_string, replacement_string)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the search_string
    set the item_list to every text item of this_text
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to the replacement_string
    set this_text to the item_list as string
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    return this_text
end replace_chars
```

This takes the folder names, which you got already, and loops over each item in the list replacing every space character with `\`. Note that the backslash needs to be escaped, and that AppleScript Editor displays the strings as including the double backslash. However you can verify that they're properly escaped with a single backslash by doing `set the clipboard to item 2 of myRepos` and pasting the resulting text into a text editor — it's just a quirk of AppleScript Editor.

The `replace_chars` function is a fairly standard boilerplate. I copied it [from Mac OS X Automation](http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-06.html).

Comment: Similarly to adayzdone's script above, this outputs results that doesn't conform to valid UNIX paths (with [:space:]'s replaced by `\ ` (backslash + space). Is it impossible to achieve `\ ` with AppleScript? Here's sample output of your script:

{"320andup", "Baseline.js\\ (jQuery\\ &\\ vanilla\\ JS\\ version)", "Bootstrap\\ (HTML,\\ CSS,\\ and\\ JS\\ toolkit\\ from\\ Twitter)", "Chirp.js\\ (Tweets\\ on\\ your\\ website,\\ simply)", "Coordino"}

Comment: As I noted, that's just the output as AppleScript Editor displays it. The actual data is in the format you specified. You can test this by adding `set the clipboard to myRepos as string` on a line before the `return` command, then paste into a text editor. You'll wee the spaces are escaped with single backslashes. If you need specific help working with the output in another way, add that to your question and I can amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Trash Man's handler posted on [MacScripter](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=11441) will escape all of the problem characters...

```
set myFolder to quoted form of "/Users/hced/Dropbox/GitHub/"

    set theFolders to every paragraph of (do shell script "find " & myFolder & " -type d -depth 1 ")
    set escFolders to {}

    repeat with aFolder in theFolders
        set end of escFolders to escape_string(aFolder as text)
    end repeat

    on escape_string(input_string)
    set output_string to ""
    set escapable_characters to " !#^$%&*?()={}[]'`~|;<>\"\\"
    repeat with chr in input_string
        if (escapable_characters contains chr) then
            set output_string to output_string & "\\" -- This actually adds ONE \ to the string.
        else if (chr is equal to "/") then
            set output_string to output_string & ":" -- Swap file system delimiters
        end if
        set output_string to output_string & chr
    end repeat
    return output_string as text
end escape_string
```

Comment: This doesn't output the path format I'm looking for. The script outputs e.g. /Users/hced/Dropbox/GitHub//Baseline.js (jQuery & vanilla JS version)   I'm struggling with how to actually output `\ ` in AppleScript strings... Seems impossible.